# Navbar Template for Bootstrap showing incorrect layout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I am doing course from Udemy Complete-e-commerce-course-java-spring-hibernate-and-mysql
I am new to Web technology and Spring.
In this app, I am using template by getbootstrap.com
Also I am build the app using Spring boot. 
Issue is that

**The top navigation bar is not coming proper.**

Below is the reference code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <!-- <div class="container"> -->

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Test of</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default,
            static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the
            responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and
            device.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar"
                role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also find below CSS file
style.css

```
    body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is how the project structure looks like

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkSYB.png)

Also, find here what I am expecting out of code. Tried enough but no idea what is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NEOk.png)

Comment: your css is not pointed to correct path, `../static/css/bootstrap.min.css` may work

Comment: done that... still isn't working

Comment: can you see `bootstrap.min.css` in `Sources` tab while inspecting in developer tools?

Comment: Yes, can see it. Yet not sure why it is not rendering it properly.

Comment: what is `navbar-header` class doing?

Comment: also you didn't specify `class="nav-link"` for `a` tags

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code works almost fine on my browser. Two small changes:

- Remove your custom CSS which is adding extra space at the navbar and making it too tall.
- Add a "container" right after your jumbotron, like this:

  <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      ...
      </div>
  </div>

After the suggested changes, this is what I see on my browser:

[image: Working Navbar]
If you are not seeing the right Navbar, this maybe pretty much related to:

- You are using a browser's cached file. When developing for web you have to make sure you clean your browser's cache if something is not displaying the way you intend. This specially applies to CSS, JS and image files.
- You're not using the right files. For example, when you try to use a file in the css directory, but they are actually stored somewhere else. I don't know Spring, but in this case, your css files seem to live inside the `static` directory. Try changing your reference to `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li  class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="active nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./">Default <span
                        class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li  class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                <li  class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

assuming you are using latest bootstrap version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using the Udemy Complete-e-commerce-course-java-spring-hibernate-and-mysql.

I found that the firefox has this error, 
`Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.js.map`. 
By Removing the line

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */ in bootstrap.min.css
```

the problem solved and the menus displayed correctly. You may have to clean the cache of the browser (CTRL + F5), If the error persists.